# How can I animate in Javascript, specifically using the Raphael library, to move a circle with x,y coordinates to a different x1,y1 coordinate

Tags: javascript, raphael

This is what I have for my initial position.

```
var drawingArea = Raphael(0,0,1200,1200);

var circle = drawingArea.circle(190,400,10);
```

Comment: Have you glanced at the documentation? It's literally the first thing on the page: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html

Comment: Is it possible to make this animation triggered by a mouse click?

Comment: I've updated the code below to include a click event, so the circle animates when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code and fiddle to include a click event. Click on the circle to make it move.

```
var drawingArea = Raphael(0,0,1200,1200);

var circle = drawingArea.circle(100,100,10);
circle.attr( { fill : "#555" } ); 
circle.click( function() {
    this.animate( { cx : 200, cy : 300 } , 500 , "bounce");
} );

var rect = drawingArea.rect(200, 100, 50, 50);
rect.animate( { x : 200, y : 300 } , 500 , "bounce");
```

There's a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/94tP4/2/